# why can not operate ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, binding, controltemplate

after code:

```
var roomTable = from desks in context.RoomToStandartDesks
            where desks.id_room == room.id
            select desks.Desk;

var tabItem = new TabItem
          {
          DataContext = roomTable,
          Header = headerText,
          };
if (controlTemplate == null)
    tabItem.Content = (object)roomTable;
else
    tabItem.Content = new ContentControl { Template = controlTemplate };
tabItems.Add(tabItem);
```

`((ContentControl)(tabItem.Content)).Content` ==    null

`((ContentControl)(((ContentControl)(tabItem)).Content)).ContentTemplate` == null

and xaml ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTabItemContentTemplate">
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=x}"/>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, Converter={StaticResource KeySimplyConvert}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Margin="10" Background="AliceBlue"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding x, Mode=TwoWay}" Y="{Binding y, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Border.RenderTransform>
            <Managerer:TablePanel DataContext="{Binding}" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Why? 
A use Silverlight 4.

Comment: err... why what?  What's failing?

Comment: ContentTemplate == null; Why might this happen? before I did, almost the same and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly that you're asking...

1. Why `((ContentControl)(tabItem.Content)).Content` is `null`, and
2. Why `((ContentControl)(((ContentControl)(tabItem)).Content)).ContentTemplate` is `null`,

... after the first bit of C#. Answers to both I think have to do with this line from your code:

```
else
    tabItem.Content = new ContentControl { Template = controlTemplate };
```

*I've simplified the parantheses hereafter, hopefully maintaining correctness. Also, casting `tabItem` to `ContentControl` to get at the same `Content` property just makes it harder to read:*

1. `((ContentControl)tabItem.Content).Content` is `null` because you never set the `Content` property of the new `ContentControl`. You only set the `Template` property.
2. `((ContentControl)tabItem.Content).ContentTemplate` is `null` for pretty much the same reason: You didn't set the `ContentTemplate`, you set the `Template`.

Comment: I do not understand what to do